# Check if user already exist

Tags: mysql, steam

First time i post on stackoverflow

I want to if the steamid get by the api already exist in the column 'steamID64', do nothing.
But if it don't, INSERT the new steamid in the same column

Here what i coded :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {

       include ('steamauth/userInfo.php'); //access steam informations

       $ID64 = $steamprofile['steamid'];


       $link = mysql_connect('xxx','xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');

       $query = "SELECT steamID64 FROM Users WHERE steamID64=".$ID64;
       $result = mysql_query($query, $link);
       $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);

       if($rowcount == 0) 
       {
          $newUser = "INSERT INTO Users SET steamID64='$ID64'";
          mysql_query($newUser, $link);
          mysql_free_result($result);
       else 
       {
          echo "User already exist"; //only for debug purpose
       }

       mysql_close($link);
   }
?>
```

The thing is he run the else but my Users table is empty
So where am i wrong ? 0_o

I know this question was already asked but i've tryed all what i found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try seeing if the query actually runs or throws an error by doing this:

```
$query = "SELECT steamID64 FROM Users WHERE steamID64='".$ID64."'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die (mysql_error($link));
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

The insert query is wrong too, it should be:

```
$newUser = "INSERT INTO Users (steamID64)  VALUES ('".$ID64.'")";
```

Anyway, you should try using PDO or Mysqli prepared statement to prevent SQL Injections, as `mysql_` are deprecated and unsecure.

## UPDATE

Before using `mysqli_` please read the docs at http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Anyway, using `mysqli_` your code will become like this:

```
$ID64 = $steamprofile['steamid'];
$link=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
$_selectQuery="SELECT steamID64 FROM Users WHERE steamID64=?";
$_select=$link->prepare($_selectQuery);
$_select->bind_param('s',$ID64);
if($_select->execute()) {
    $_select->store_result();
    $rowcount=$_select->num_rows;
    if($rowcount==0) {
        $_select->free_result();
        $_insertQuery="INSERT INTO Users (steamID64) VALUES (?)";
        $_insert=$link->prepare($_insertQuery);
        $_insert->bind_param('s',$ID64);

        if($_insert->execute()) {
            //NEW RECORD INSERTED
        } else {
            echo $link->error;
        }
        $_insert->free_result();
    } else {
        //DUPLICATE ENTRY
    }
} else {
    echo $link->error;
}
```

P.S. I'm using object-oriented `mysqli_` functions

`mysqli->execute()` returns TRUE if the statement has succeded, otherwise it will return FALSE, but, anyway, in case of an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` the `mysqli` object will also contain an `affected_rows` property, which represents the number of rows affected by the statement.
So, even if the `execute` works, you can check how many rows were actually inserted.

Comment: I said me no database selected but in the mysql_connect i have my database in fourth argument and what it will look like in mysqli ?

Comment: You have probably mistyped the database name, or you forgot to create one. Look at the updated answer to see an example of `mysqli_` usage

Comment: The script work well but when the INSERT is executed the echo in if( $_insert->execute) is not executed at all i don't know why ^^

Comment: Thanks for all mate you helped me a lot, i can't upvote you but Thankd :D

Comment: We're here to help as much as we can, just remember to avoid old and unsecure `mysql_`. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table only has one field, change your code to this:

```
$newUser = "INSERT INTO Users(steamID64) VALUES('".$ID64."')";
```

However, I would recommend looking into PDO as this is open to a SQL injection attack.

Please insert other fields along with steamID64 if necessary.